# Simple complex characters of a group $G$

Tags: representation-theory

I want to prove that, given some group $G$ and some element  $g \in G$ with $g \neq 1_G$, $G$ has a simple complex representation with character $\chi$ for which $\chi(g)$ has a negative real part. In order to do so, I want to use the following result:

Let $\chi_1 \cdots, \chi_r$ be the characters of simple complex representations of a group $G$, with degrees $d_1, \cdots, d_r$, respectively. Then, if $g \in G$ and $g \neq 1_G$ we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^r d_i\chi_i(g) = 0.
$$

If there exist some simple complex representation with character $\chi_s$ with real part different from zero then there must exist some other simple complex representation with character $\chi_t$ with real part of opposite sign, given that the degrees $d_1, \cdots, d_r$ are all natural numbers different from zero (except for the trivial representation).

Comment: The trivial character is one of the characters in the result you quote!

Comment: I don't understant how it helps to prove the result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\chi_1$ is the trivial character and let $g\not=1_G$. Then $\chi_1(g)=1$. Thus,
\begin{equation}
d_1+\sum_{i=2}^rd_i\chi_i(g)=0.
\end{equation}
Comparing the real parts,
\begin{equation}
d_1+\sum_{i=2}^rd_i\Re (\chi_i(g))=0.
\end{equation}
Since each $d_i$ is greater than $0$ this forces that there exist at least one $\chi_i$ satisfying $\Re(\chi_i(g))<0$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome.